# My Redux store is an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am integrating Redux into my React Native app.

I've been having trouble passing the state down into my components, and realised its because the initial state begins with a key of '0', e.g.

```
{
  '0': {
    key: 'value'
  }
}
```

I.e. it seems to be an array.

So that if I have in my `connect` export:

```
export default connect(state => ({
    key: state.key,
    reduxState: state
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(MyActions, dispatch)
  })
)(MyReduxApp);
```

`key` is always undefined, however, `reduxState` gets passed down successfully. (Of course it is not advised to send the whole state down)

The root component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import DataReducer from '../Reducers/Data';
import MyRedApp from './JustTunerApp';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers([DataReducer]); // ready for more reducers.. 
// const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
const store = createStore(reducer);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log ("store.getState:")
    console.log (store.getState())
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MyReduxApp />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

My reducer looks like:

```
const initialState = {
  key : "value"
};

export default function key(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Is the store returned as an array? How should I pass it into the `connect` method?

If I pass it in as `key: state[0].key` then it works, but this doesn't seem right according to all the examples I've seen..

Comment: As I see in your reducer you don't return `state`;

Comment: Whatever is returned from your root reducer is exactly what is passed to `connect`. If you use middleware/store enhancers it could affect the value.

Comment: @MichelleTilley thanks however I removed the middleware (`redux-thunk`) but still get the same. But your comment gives me a clue to investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have posted the root component earlier... that held the clue.

`const reducer = combineReducers([DataReducer])`

should have been

`const reducer = combineReducers({DataReducer})`

the lesson here is don't rush and look at the docs more closely!